# How to add two inline formset to the form dynamically?

Tags: django

[image]

In admin page, It can do done easily, but it seems problem in View Page. I've tried but failed many times. As I am newbie to django. How can I achieve this type of formset in Custom View page?? (Create and Update both)
I used jQuery Plugin for Dynamic FormSet. and this is my code in views.py

```
class ExamAdd(CreateView):
    model = Exam
    fields = ['title', 'examRoom']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(ExamAdd, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        print('This is data for exam add',data)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['dateformset'] = ExamDateFormSet(self.request.POST)
            data ['shiftformset'] = ExamShiftFormSet(self.request.POST)
        else:
            data['dateformset'] = ExamDateFormSet()
            data['shiftformset'] = ExamShiftFormSet()
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        dateformset = context['dateformset']
        shiftformset = context ['shiftformset']
        with transaction.atomic():
            self.object = form.save()

            if dateformset.is_valid() and shiftformset.is_valid():
                dateformset.instance = self.object
                shiftformset.instance = self.object
                instances  = dateformset.save(commit = False)
                for instance in instances:
                    instance.save()
                instances  = shiftformset.save(commit = False)
                for instance in instances:
                    instance.save()
                invigilatorAssignment = InvigilatorAssignmentForm()
        return super(ExamAdd, self).form_valid(form)



class ExamUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Exam
    fields = ['title', 'examRoom']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')
    examDateFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Exam,ExamDate,form = ExamDateAddForm,formset=BaseExamDateEditFormSet2,extra = 1,can_delete=True)
    examShiftFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Exam,Shift,form = ExamShiftAddForm,formset = BaseShiftEditFormSet2,extra = 1,can_delete=True)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(ExamUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['dateformset'] = self.examDateFormSet(self.object,self.request.POST)
            data ['shiftformset'] = self.examShiftFormSet(self.object,self.request.POST)
        else:
            data['dateformset'] = self.examDateFormSet(self.object)
            data['shiftformset'] = self.examShiftFormSet(self.object)
        print ("This is data",data)
        print ("THis is objetc",self.object)
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        dateformset = context['dateformset']
        shiftformset = context ['shiftformset']
        with transaction.atomic():
            self.object = form.save()

            if dateformset.is_valid() and shiftformset.is_valid:
                if dateformset.has_changed():
                    dateformset.instance = self.object
                    dateformset.save()
                if shiftformset.has_changed():
                    shiftformset.instance = self.object
                    shiftformset.save()
                invigilatorAssignment = InvigilatorAssignmentForm()
            else:
                print ("DateFormSet Not Valid",dateformset.errors)
                print ("ShiftFormSet Not Valid",shiftformset.errors)
        return super(ExamUpdate, self).form_valid(form)
```

and in template.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title %}{% endblock %}
{% block mainContent %}
    <style>

    </style>    
<h2>Add Exam</h2>
    <hr>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form  action = '' method="post" >{% csrf_token %}
           {%include 'includes/form.html'%}

            <table class="table">
                {{ dateformset.management_form|crispy }}
                {% for form in dateformset.forms %}
                    {% if forloop.first %}
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                                <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
                            {% endfor %}

                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                    {% endif %}
                    <tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %} dateformset formset_row">
                        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                            <td>
                                {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
                                {{ field }}
                            </td>

                        {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>

            <table class="table">
                    {{ shiftformset.management_form }}
                    {% for form in shiftformset.forms %}
                        {% if forloop.first %}
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                                    <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>

                                {% endfor %}

                            </tr>

                            </thead>
                        {% endif %}
                        <tr class="{% cycle row1 row2 %} shiftformset formset_row">
                            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                                <td>
                                    {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
                                    {% if forloop.first %}
                                        {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                                            {{ hidden }}
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    {% endif %}
                                    {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
                                    {{ field }}
                                </td>

                            {% endfor %}


                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}

                </table>


            <input type="submit" value="Save"/> <a href="{% url 'index' %}">Back to the list</a>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'formset/jquery.formset.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.dateformset').formset({
            addText: 'Add Date',
            deleteText: 'Delete',
            prefix: 'examdates'
        });
        $('.shiftformset').formset({
            addText: 'Add Shifts',
            deleteText: 'Delete',
            prefix: 'shifts'
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}


</body>
</html>
```

And This is my repo for this project. https://github.com/regmirabindra/Invigilator-Management

Comment: can you show ur code

Comment: @c.grey I edited my post and added code. Please have a look and help me.

Comment: what's the problem? error? result? be specific, "it's not working" isn't specific.

Comment: @dirkgroten Nothing happens really, it just redirect to index page and when i check back, there is no update to element.

Comment: To debug, add the `def post(self, request, **kwargs)` method that just returns the super() method and set a breakpoint there. Check what's being posted (look into `request.POST`). That might help.

Comment: @dirkgroten request.POST is correct data, i.e those which I deleted have DELETE on and new data is added alongside but I think there is a problem while saving those value. but dunno what

Comment: ShiftFormSet Not Valid [{'id': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}]
Also this error is showing.

Comment: Then you know why ShiftFormSet is not valid and therefore not saved. Check the form you’re using in your form set, and what’s expected for ‘id’. Actually ‘id’ should not be required because for new instances it’s generated automatically. How is ShiftFormSet defined?

Comment: ExamDateFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Exam,ExamDate,form = ExamDateAddForm,extra = 1)
ExamShiftFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Exam,Shift,form= ExamShiftAddForm,extra = 1)